# Webpage to browse dynamic folder structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a novice web developer.
I am trying to create a webpage to browse a directory structure and the files within. The problem is there are too many folders and files to create hyperlinks manually. Is there any easier way to achieve this?

I have already checked this: http://neotechworld.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/folder-tree-structure-using-jquery/
But, I don't want a folder tree view. I would like something more elegant.

PS: The webpage is to be used offline and I am not going to host it or something.
There also is no question of security because the user is gonna have access to folder structure anyways. I just want to represent it in a nicer way.

Comment: "But, I don't want a folder tree view. I would like something more elegant" So, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Something like a multilevel webpage menu...

Comment: So, you could still use a tree view and modificate its design (css). Seems not so hard to do even this would be not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to see about nanotree on this http://nanotree.sourceforge.net/